# How do you remove the overlapping contents of one List from another List?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
listA.add("a");
listA.add("b");
listA.add("c");
listA.add("d");



List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
listB.add("c");
listB.add("d");
listB.add("e");
listB.add("f");
```

`ListB` contains two elements that are also present in `ListA` (`"c"` and `"d"`).

Is there a clean way to make sure that `listB` does not contain these or any other overlapping elements that may already exist in `listA`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
listB.removeAll(listA)
```

This would make your `listB` contain only `[e, f]`.

Comment: this only works out of the box with basic object type lists (string etc) for your own objects you need to define object.equals method so it will mean something with your object. read more on equals here:stackoverflow.com/questions/8338326/…